# How to draw following picture using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to draw the following picture using tikz, but i don't know how to color it as 3d object and how to place upper arrow overlay other arrow?

The following, is my try:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,xscale=.8]
 \draw  (-1,8) arc (90:-82.8:8 and 3);
 \draw  (-1,8)-- (-1,7);
 \draw  (7,4)-- (7,5);
 \draw  (-1,7) arc (90:10:8 and 3);
 \draw  (7,4) arc (0:-82.8:8 and 3);
 \draw  (0,1.02) --(0,.5)--(-1.5,1.54) node[left]{cc}--(0,2.5) --(0,2);
 %----------------------------------
 \draw  (-1,1) arc (90:-82.8:8 and 3);
 \draw  (-1,0)-- (-1,1);
 \draw  (7,-3)-- (7,-2);
 \draw  (-1,0) arc (90:10:8 and 3);
 \draw  (7,-3) arc (0:-82.8:8 and 3);
 \draw  (0,-5.98) --(0,-6.5)--(-1.5,-5.48) node[left]{cc}--(0,-4.5) --(0,-5);
 %----------------------------------
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 3d effect and the overlay can both be implemented by the fill option for `\draw`. There could be nicer solutions. Below I did a minimum modification from your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,xscale=.8]
\draw[fill=gray] (-1,7) -- (-1,8) arc (90:-7:8 and 3);
\draw  (-1,8) arc (90:-82.8:8 and 3);
\draw  (7,4)-- (7,5);
\draw[fill=white]  (-1,7) arc (90:10:8 and 3);
\draw  (7,4) arc (0:-82.8:8 and 3);
\draw  (0,1.02) --(0,.5)--(-1.5,1.54) node[left]{cc}--(0,2.5) --(0,2);
%----------------------------------
\draw[fill=gray] (-1,0)-- (-1,1) arc (90:-7.8:8 and 3);
\draw  (-1,1) arc (90:-82.8:8 and 3);
\draw  (7,-3)-- (7,-2);
\draw[fill=white]  (-1,0) arc (90:10:8 and 3);
\draw  (7,-3) arc (0:-82.8:8 and 3);
\draw  (0,-5.98) --(0,-6.5)--(-1.5,-5.48) node[left]{cc}--(0,-4.5) --(0,-5);
%----------------------------------
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit:
For gradient coloring, it can be done by setting `shading = axis`.

[image]

You may also set `shading angle=x` for some angle x for different visual effects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want a gradient coloring.

Comment: @C.F.G I thought that was a bad scanning... I think `shading` is what you need. See above.